# Default configuration in zuul routing

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

My project needs a default config routing in zuul like below:

zuul:

```
test1:  
    service-id: TEST1  
    path: /test1/** 

resource:  
  path: /error/**  
  url: http://test/Sample 

default:  
  (This needs to be rendered whenever request has url other than above mentioned).
```

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can place `/**` url routes in the end of the `zuul.routes` like the below.

```
zuul:  
  routes:
    test1:  
      service-id: TEST1  
      path: /test1/** 
    resource:  
      path: /error/**  
      url: http://test/Sample 
    default:  
      path: /**
      url: <url that you want to forward>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but the path /** overwrites all the above mentioned service-id's and urls mapped.

Comment: which release are you using ? And, could you show me the error message ?

Comment: Actually what happens is that whenever I am trying to access the above end points using rest client, I am facing 404 not found error like below   {
"timestamp": 1500438881684,
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/test1/heartbeat"
}.  When I check my mapping all service id's are overwritten by /**. Regarding release let me get back to you

Comment: 1.1.0.RELEASE is the version used by us.

Comment: I have even tried with 1.3.1.RELEASE. Its not working in that too.

Comment: Coming from a previous version, your reference of default helped solve my issue of zuul.routes.*.path no longer working after an update.